# More information about content in Link field autocomplete dropdown?

Tags: 8, navigation

In a project we have a Link field where editors can link to internal content or external content.

There are several cases where nodes of different content types have the same title.

Is there a way to display more information than just the node title in Link fields autocomplete widget - so that we can make it easier for Editors to pick the right node?

We are using LinkIt but that does not support the link module at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The autocompletion matches are provided by `EntityAutocompleteMatcher::getMatches`. The format is hardcoded as `$key = "$label ($entity_id)"`. Label and entity id come from selection manager, which packages entity id and label pairs in an array keyed by entity bundle, so that could be used as a source for adding content type into the results. You'll need to override `system.entity_autocomplete` route's controller to get to your own matcher.

The same controller is used for rendering the selection dropdown though it does not display the entity ids, only labels (in `web/core/misc/autocomplete.js`). Overriding that is another thing you'll need to do.

Comment: Thanks. I was dreaming of a pointer to some contrib module I was unaware of. Looks like this solution may take more time than I have; I'll get back to this answer if I go down this route.

Comment: @BerntAndreasDrange I encountered the same sort of issue in a project I was working on. My implementation is different to the one suggested by holist but I created something that can append bundle or vocabulary labels to the respective type of entity reference autocomplete field. It is part of my module [Starter](https://github.com/brynj-digital/starter)

Comment: Hei BrynJ, thanks for that - looks/sounds like what we need. Would you consider creating that piece as a contrib module on drupal.org?

Comment: @BerntAndreasDrange possibly, although not sure when I will have time to do so (it's possibly a bit hacky in implementation too, but needs must sometimes). Feel free to take the relevant code from my module and spin it out into your module though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple module that I released on github. With some modification you may display anything you need in the autocomplete results/suggestions.

https://github.com/minnur/Alter-Entity-Autocomplete

Comment: Thanks minnur! Have you considered putting this on drupal.org?

Comment: @BerntAndreasDrange you're welcome! I will think about releasing the module. I have very limited time for contrib work, if I have absolutely nothing else to do I will look into that :)

Comment: The ideal improvement to the Link field is to support the use of a View to define the autocomplete options - as the Entityref field does. This would allow limiting content types, adding any info you like to the title, limiting to published items, etc.